# Atiyah-Macdonald, Proposition 2.12, uniqueness of the tensor product.

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

The following is a result from Atiyah-Macdonald, defining and showing existence and uniqueness of tensor product of modules over a commutative ring.

> **Proposition 2.12.** Let $M, N$ be $A$-modules. There exists a pair $(T,g)$ consisting of an  $A$-module $T$ and an $A$-bilinear mapping $g: M \times N \rightarrow T$. with the following property: 
>   Given any $A$-module $P$ and any $A$-bilinear mapping $f: M \times N \rightarrow P$, there exists a unique $A$-linear mapping $f':T \rightarrow P$ such that $f = f' \circ g$. 
>   Moreover, if $(T,g)$ and $(T',g')$ are two pairs with this property, then there exists a unique isomorphism $j:T \rightarrow T'$ such that $j \circ g = g'$.

The proof of this proposition starts with uniqueness statement, which is the thing I have some problems with.

> Proof. i) Uniqueness. Replacing $(P,f)$ by $(T',g')$ we get a unique $j:T \rightarrow T'$ such that $g' = j \circ g$. Interchanging roles of $T$ and $T'$, we get $j':T' \rightarrow T$ such that $g = j' \circ g'$. Each composition $j \circ j', j' \circ j$ must be the identity, and therefore $j$ is an isomorphism.

I do not understand how the authors at this stage can conclude that $j \circ j'$ and $j' \circ j$ are identity homomorphisms. From the equations we get $g = j' \circ j \circ g$, which shows that $j' \circ j$ is the identity on the image of $g$. Since $j,j'$ are homomorphisms, if we know that the image of $g$ generates $T$, then I could conclude that indeed $j' \circ j$ is the identity, but without this assumption I do not see how this can be done.

Of course, when constructing $T$ explicitly one sees that indeed image of $g$ generates $T$. But even then, if I get another pair $(T', g')$ satisfying the hypotheses of the proposition, where image of $g'$ does not necessarily generate $T'$, I will obtain $g' = j \circ j' \circ g'$, and again I won't be able to conclude that $j \circ j'$ is the identity on entire $T'$.

So, I guess my question is if I must add the hypothesis on $g, g'$ that their images generate $T, T'$ as $A$-modules to make this proof work, or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: It is part of the assumed property. Both $j' \circ j$ and the identity map makes the required diagram commute. By uniqueness, they have to be the same map. Same goes for $j \circ j'$.

Comment: The uniqueness of the tensor product is a purely formal property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First replace $(T',g')$ by  $(T,g)$. Then there is an *unique* morphism $k:T\to T$ such that $k \circ g = g$, namely, $k={\rm id}$. Since $j' \circ j$ is another morphism with the same property, then  $j' \circ j={\rm id}$.

Comment: Oh, that was indeed very simple. Thanks.

Comment: OK, good luck!....